# Erro tentando apagar arquivo de imagem?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando fazer uma atualização de imagem em um cadastro. Quando faço essa atualização quero trocar a imagem existente para a nova imagem da atualização.

Para isso estou usando o `File.Exists` e o `File.Delete` onde eu verifico se já existe uma imagem e se existir apago e substituo pela nova imagem.

O problema é que isso sempre me retorna uma exceção e não apaga a imagem existente.

A exceção é

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\xampp\htdocs\IguanaBarWS\app\webroot\img\categorias\3.jpg' because it is being used by another process.`

Como posso resolver esse problema ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
private void saveImageCategoria(String imgName) 
{
    Image img = pictureBox1.Image;            
    Image imgResize = ResizeImage.getResizeImage(img, new Size(50,50));
    if (File.Exists(PATH_FOLDER + imgName)) 
    {
        File.Delete(PATH_FOLDER + imgName);
    }   
    imgResize.Save(PATH_FOLDER + imgName);
    pictureBox1.Image = null;         
}
```

Comment: Como você está carregando esta imagem para o PictureBox? Podes colocar o código desta função na pergunta?

Comment: Provavelmente você deve estar enfrentando problemas de permissão ao diretório onde a imagem está armazenada, tente fazer o mesmo processo acessando em um outro diretório que esteja sem restrições de acesso.

Comment: @JulioBorges Desculpe me intrometer mas, provavelmente, não tem nada a ver com isso. O problema dele é que a imagem pode estar referenciada no PictureBox

Comment: Opa @jbueno, sem problemas, estamos aqui pra ajudar a comunidade.

Comment: @jbueno pra add a imagem ao PictureBox faço assim: `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(PATH_FOLDER + this.categoria.imagem);`

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque, com o perdão do trocadilho infame, a imagem está sendo usada por outro processo.

Quem está usando a imagem é o `PictureBox` e para que seja possível excluir esta imagem você deve chamar o método `Dispose()` da propriedade `Image` do `PictureBox`. Veja um exemplo:

```
private void ExcluirImagem() 
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

    File.Delete("Caminho/Da/Imagem.png");
}
```

Um detalhe importante é que você não precisa verificar se determinado arquivo existe antes de tentar excluí-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, encontrei a solução aqui: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/309482 . Como o @jbueno sugeriu a imagem ficava `locked` no pictureBox. Obrigado @jbueno

para resolver fiz assim.

```
//set image pictureBox
FileStream fs = new FileStream(PATH_FOLDER + this.categoria.imagem, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
            fs.Close();

//delete image
if (File.Exists(PATH_FOLDER + imgName)) {
                File.Delete(PATH_FOLDER + imgName);
            }
```